# Hide a column in cross-tab depending on the value of parameter (Crystal Reports XI)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using Crystal Reports XI (R2) and have a cross-tab which displays information about flights. There is the 'Total' column' as well as the Arrivals and Departures columns which are created automatically thanks to the grouping condition. What I'm trying to do is to have the 'flight directions' parameter, where the user can select 'All, departures only or arrivals only' values and according to this selection the cross-tab would have one or two columns. How can this be achieved? I tried using the following formula(and have the suppress empty columns option enabled) :

```
if {?Pm-@flight_direction_description} = "Departures Only"
then
if ({Command_1.IsArrival} = 1)
then 0
else {Command_1.IsArrival}
```

which indeed works (only one column is displayed) but then under the Departures column it lists all the flights (so the departures column is the same as the Total column) whereas it should only display information about departing flights.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar situations come up; while certainly not ideal, and if no one has any better suggestions, you could create Detail A, Detail B and Detail C sections, all of them suppressed.  From there...

- You could put your "All" crosstab in Detail A
- Create a second crosstab for Destinations only, and put that in Detail B
- Create a third crosstab for Arrivals only, and put that in Detail C

Then, in your Detail A, B and C sections, you can condtionally unsuppress the section you want based on the parameter passed in.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like something that would work. Wonder if there is an option to select the columns depending on the parameter passed by the user in the latest version of Crystal? What do you mean by a section? A subreport?

Comment: Wherever your first crosstab is (either group header/footer or detail section), you can right-click in the left margin and select "Insert Section Below" to add a new section.

Comment: The only issue with that is that it will display one crosstab underneath another, while I really need to display them next to each other.

Comment: I apologize, I thought you only wanted to display one crosstab at at time, not all three of them.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately that's the client requirements, the total column should be always displayed and depending on the user selection also one (or both) the Arrivals and Departures columns.